# Software debounce for Android buttons

Tags: android, android-button, keyboard-events, bounce

I have a simple `ImageButton` in my Android program which, when clicked, appends a "0" in a `TextView`. When this button is long clicked, it is supposed to append "+" in that `TextView`. The program works fine but I'm facing a typical key bouncing effect. When I long press the button, it do appends a "+", but when I release the button, it also appends a "0". It seems like Android registers a second single click when long click ends. How can I eliminate this? Here's what I'm doing:

```
ImageButton button0=(ImageButton)V.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonzero);
        button0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                enterNumber.append("0");

            }
        });
        button0.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                enterNumber.append("+");
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return `true` in the `OnLongClickListener`, to inform other listeners that the event has been consumed and does not need to be actioned upon further down the line :

```
button0.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        enterNumber.append("+");
        return true;
    }
});
```

Source of information : [Android javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html#onLongClick(android.view.View))